# Memoize and lodash times get index, create unique text inputs

Tags: reactjs, lodash, jsx, memoise

I have an icon button with a plus sign. Each time when I click it I'm creating a text input. I simplified the code in the example but in my project I am trying to use it to create social icons, where in each text input you add the social icon name/or url. The code is JSX in React:

```
export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {  

        const { attributes: { totalItems, textInputValue }, setAttributes } = this.props;

        const createItem = memoize( ( totalItems ) => {
            return times( totalItems, () => renderItems( totalItems, textInputValue ) );
        } );

         return (
            <IconButton                 
              label={ __( 'Add text input' ) }
              icon="plus"
              onClick={ () => setAttributes( { totalItems: totalItems + 1 } ) }
            />

            { createItem( totalItems ) }
        )
    }
}

function renderItems( index, textInputValue  ) {
    return (

     <TextControl
        label={ __( 'My text input' ) }
        value={ textInputValue }
        onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { textInputValue: value } ) }
     />  /* how can I get unique text inputs? */

     { index } /* this doesn't return the index of the element created */
    )
}
```

The problem: the same text input is being created. Is there a way to add index or map to memoize/times in order to render unique inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash's [`_.times()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#times) returns the `index` to the callback:

```js
const totalItems = 5;

const result = _.times(totalItems, index => ({ index }));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

So in your case, the component should be something like this:

**Note:** I've removed memoize, since calling it multiple times in render doesn't actually memoize anything. If you need memoize, you should move the function creation to a property of the object, so calls would be cached.

```
export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {  
        const { attributes: { totalItems, textInputValue }, setAttributes } = this.props;

        const createItem = (totalItems, textInputValue) =>
          times(totalItems, index => renderItems(index, textInputValue );

         return (
            <IconButton                 
              label={ __( 'Add text input' ) }
              icon="plus"
              onClick={ () => setAttributes( { totalItems: totalItems + 1 } ) }
            />

            { createItem( totalItems ) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting the index now! I have updated my question. I'm not sure how to generate text inputs with unique values based on how many I create using times.

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you mean by unique values. However, you can append the index to any base value, and it will be unique. You can also use lodash's [`_.uniqueId()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqueId)

Comment: this seems to work as well `const createItem = () => times(totalItems, index => renderItems(index, textInputValue ) )` Is it ok to use like that?

Comment: Sure. Since you've got `totalItems` in the context. When you call it, just call `createItem()`.